# Windows phone: Loading data in a listview is very slow (Appcelerator Titanium)

Tags: windows-phone, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I have a problem with my windows phone app.
I try to load about 80 items in a listview. When I do that in the controller and I create an instance of the controller at the moment that the app starts, i get a timeout message.

When I call the loadData method after the app has been started it works but to load the data takes about 27 seconds (on the device), in the emulator it takes about 4 seconds, which is much better but still a bit long in my opinion.

I have no idea what causes this delay. Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

This is the code for loading the data in the listview. (Titanium SDK 5.3.0.GA)

```
function loadData() {
var fruitSection = Ti.UI.createListSection({ headerTitle: 'Fruits'});
var fruitDataSet = [
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}},
    {properties: { title: 'test item'}}
];
fruitSection.setItems(fruitDataSet);
sections.push(fruitSection);
listView.sections = sections;
Ti.API.info('done');
}
```